# angular-strap issue in mean.js

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap, meanjs

I have Mean.js architecture, and i need to make some modals windows. But when I'm include `['ngAnimate', 'mgcrea.ngStrap']` I have this issue:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'undefined' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I have already included angular-strap components:

all.js

```
            js: [
            'public/lib/angular/angular.js',
            'public/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js', 
            'public/lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js', 
            'public/lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js', 
            'public/lib/angular-touch/angular-touch.js', 
            'public/lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js', 
            'public/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
            'public/lib/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils.js',
            'public/lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
            'public/lib/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.min.js', 
            'public/lib/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.tpl.min.js', 
            'public/lib/angular-strap/dist/modules/modal.min.js', 
            'public/lib/angular-strap/dist/modules/modal.tpl.min.js',
            'public/lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js',
            'public/lib/lodash/dist/lodash.js',

        ]
```

controller.js:

```
    'use strict';
angular.module('angular-strap' ['ngAnimate', 'mgcrea.ngStrap']).controller('AngularStrapController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.modal = {
            "title": "Title",
            "content": "Hello Modal<br />This is a multiline message!"
        }
    }
])
```

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: I guess this isn't the issue, but you're loading two angular-animate...

Comment: however it's not working

Comment: Is every file with it's right path?

Comment: yes, i think. I don't know what wrong with this libraries, maybe something wrong at my controller. I showed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a comma after `angular-strap`

Correct:
`angular.module('angular-strap' , ['ngAnimate', 'mgcrea.ngStrap'])`